Example of $\{0, 1\}^{\omega}$ space requiring multiple isolated point removals to obtain a perfect set
I'm looking for an example of the space $X = \{0,1\}^{\omega}$ and a closed subset $F$ of $X$ such that we need to remove isolated points repeatedly (more than 2 times) from $F$ to obtain a perfect set $P$. In other words, if we define $F_0 = F$ and $F_{n+1} = F_n \setminus \{$isolated points of $F_n\}$, then there should exist an integer $N > 2$ such that $F_N = P$ is perfect, but $F_n$ is not perfect for all $n < N$.
I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide such an example and explain the construction of the sets $F$, $P$, and $C$ (where $C = F \setminus P$ is the countable set in the Cantor - Bendixson theorem) in detail.
Thank you for your assistance!

Intuitively, just start with (say) a homeomorphic copy of $[-2,-1]\cup \mathbb{Z}$ and replace the isolated points with ("nonoverlapping") copies of $\{0\}\cup\{{1\over n}\}$.
In a bit more detaily, here's how we can "pad out" the Cantor-Bendixson process. Suppose $C$ is a closed set with nonempty set of isolated points $I$. Let $U_i$ ($i\in I$) be open sets such that $i\in U_i$ and if $i\not=j$ then $cl(U_i)\cap cl(U_j)=\emptyset$. Finally, for each $i\in I$ let $X_i$ be a homeomorphic copy of $\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ lying entirely inside $U_i$. If we let $$\hat{C}=(C\setminus I)\cup \bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$$ ("replace each point in $I$ by a copy of $\omega+1$") then we get a new closed set whose Cantor-Bendixson process takes one more step than that of $C$ itself to terminate. Iterating this repeatedly can give rise to arbitrarily large finite Cantor-Bendixson ranks; it's a fun exercise to modify this to yield a closed set with infinite rank.
